# SCSS color variable failing to compile in Angular component

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I'm at a loss I must be missing something. This is very simple. Here is the angular component referencing the scss file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'base-table',
    templateUrl: './html/base.table.html',
    styleUrls: ['./scss/base.table.scss']
})
```

Here is the part of the scss (simplified) that is not working:

```
$orange: #ED7000;
#table-hscroll {
    --scrollbar-thumb-color: $orange;
}
```

If I don't use the variable, everything works fine. As soon as I use the variable, the color disappears. I've specified scss in angular cli and assume it will be compiled correctly when accessing it directly from a component, but that appears to not be the case.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
```

Is there something I don't know about how scss works when directly referenced from components. Is my file not being compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
$orange: #ED7000;

#table-hscroll {
    --scrollbar-thumb-color: #{$orange};
}
```

Comment: Will try this out. I still use this scroll for all my tables and it's been working fine for a year but I've been stuck with a hard-coded color. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. I can confirm this was all I needed. Was just a syntax issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is not directly in your components scss but instead in a global stylesheet, you have to import that global stylesheet within your component's stylesheet. You will need to do this for all your components if they have separate stylesheets.

So within `./scss/base.table.scss'` import the stylesheet that contains your variable.

Comment: But the variable is in the component scss. And when I inspect in browser, it looks like this --scrollbar-thumb-color: $orange;. So it's simply not compiling the scss. I would eventually move all these global, but I'm trying to get the simplest thing to work first.

Comment: Have you tried without using a css variable? For example just `scrollbar-thumb-color: $orange;`

Comment: Yes. If I just use css, it works fine. `scrollbar-thumb-color: #ED7000;` works fine. But I want to avoid having to go back and change colors all over the application - would rather globalize the variable -- but it won't even work when put in the scss file.

Comment: Just messed around with it and it seems your issue is related to the property you are trying to use the SCSS variable with (--scrollbar-thumb-color). Test it out and try colouring something simple like a background colour with `$orange`.

Comment: Nailed it! That was it! Now have to sort out how to address that screwy property.